# How to pass an array to a function by reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm looking how to pass a string/array to a function, I have tried to pass by value, but it doesn't seem to work, I have looked online and seen by reference but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Can anyone help?

Comment: could you possible show an example, im fairly new to C++ it helps to see the code in practice, if its not too much trouble? thanks

Comment: Easy: `void f(std::array<T, N>& par)` for an array (or `std::vector<T>` for a dynamic array), `void f(std::string& par)` for a string. But why not show some code about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare a function that takes an array of 10 ints by reference like this:

```
void f(int (&arr)[10]);
```

You call it like this

```
int arr[10];
f(arr);
```

You can templatize your function

```
template<class T, int N>
void f(T (&arr)[N]);
```

Comment: the string i am passing is read in from a file, so it doesn't have a static elment size, anyway i could get around this? thanks

Comment: @user1141945: No, there isn't.  Array types in C++ must have their size specified at compile-time.  Dynamic "arrays" are actually pointers, not arrays.

Comment: Aren't arrays passed by reference anyway? What's the difference between `void f(int (&arr)[10]);` and `void f(int arr[10]);` ?

Comment: @Aaron: The latter loses the size information and is *completely equivalent* to `void f(int* arr);`, while the former is a true reference and will only accept actual arrays (T[N] notation) with exactly that size. The latter would also accept raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using variable size arrays you should use something like this:

```
void someFunc(char* szString, int cbChars)
{
    for (int nChar == 0; nChar < cbChars; nChar++)
    {   // Do something with the char array
        szString[nChar] = 'A'; // Convert string to "AAAAAA..."
    {
}

void callerFunc()
{
    char szString[255];
    // read file...
    // put file contents in szString
    // and call the above function passing the string 'by reference'
    someFunc(szString, 255);
}
```

That is, just pass a pointer to the array (must be the same type) and its size (so you know where to stop and avoid exceptions).

You can do the same for any array of any data-type, there's a good tutorial on pointers: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent compiler like recent gcc and visual studio (that provide C++11 containers) you could use instead of a raw array a std::array and make things more clear on reading.

Here is Armen Tsirunyan answer with std::array :

```
void f( std::array<int,10> & arr );
```

You call it like this

```
std::array<int,10> arr;
f(arr);
```

You can templatize your function

```
template<class T, int N>
void f( std::array<T,N> & arr );
```